# join data to a .kmz or .kml and plot

Tags: r, rgdal, r-sf

I'm somewhat new to R and totally new to R geospatially.  I'm trying to read a downloadable `.kml`, join my own data to it, and plot the data.

The `.kml` is from this home page: https://www.cnrfc.noaa.gov/ -- the "Drainage Basins" layer from the 'Download Overlay Files' dropdown menu right below the map (file size is tiny).

```
library(rgdal)
library(tidyverse)

# read in the downloaded file
# downloads as "basins.kml", "layer name ID'd from viewing .kml as text
spatialpolydf <- readOGR("basins.kml", "cnrfc_09122018_basins_thin")

#view the polygons (california river basins)
ggplot() + geom_path(data = spatialpolydf, aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group))  +
           coord_quickmap()

#create example observations for the 339 river basins
observation_value2 <- sample(1:1000, 339)

#get the basin names #not sure this is reliable
observation_place <- spatialpolydf@data 

#create data.frame for joining to the spatial data frame
#but, I'm not sure I quite need a data.frame, maybe just a tibble or data.table?

obs_place_value <- data.frame(observation_place, observation_value2)
```

So from here, I'm hoping to join & visualize the observations using the libraries above or any others, with something like:

```
spatialpolydf_withjoineddata <- some_join_function(obs_place_value,
                                                   spatialpolydf)
ggplot() + geom_path(data = spatialpolydf_withjoineddata, aes(x=long, y=lat,
           group = group, fill = observation_value2))  + coord_quickmap()
```

It seems it would be nice to have one object/data.frame of 339 rows of the data, where each row can represent multiple polygons like ESRI's attribute table does, with commonly unneeded geometric data hidden. I'm open to all suggestions, but ideally I'll learn methods that leave the data in a useable/flexible format for later processing/visualization rather than a quick fix just to see these data.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tagged your question with the `sf` tag, so I think you probably want to learn more about `sf`. Below is a script to convert your `sp` object to an `sf` object, join your data frame `obs_place_value`, and then visualize the data with `observation_value2` as the fill value. The `sf` object is a special kind of data frame, so function works on data frame like `left_join` can also work on the `sf` object. `geom_sf` is the function to plot the `sf` object.

```
library(rgdal)
library(tidyverse)
library(sp)
library(sf)

# read in the downloaded file
# downloads as "basins.kml", "layer name ID'd from viewing .kml as text
spatialpolydf <- readOGR("Data/basins.kml", "cnrfc_09122018_basins_thin")

# set.seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)

#create example observations for the 339 river basins
observation_value2 <- sample(1:1000, 339)

#create data.frame for joining to the spatial data frame
obs_place_value <- data.frame(observation_place, observation_value2)

# Convert spatialpolydf to an sf object
spatialpolysf <- spatialpolydf %>% st_as_sf()

# Join the data
spatialpolysf2 <- spatialpolysf %>%
  left_join(obs_place_value, by = c("Name", "Description"))

# Use ggplot2 to plot the data
ggplot(spatialpolysf2) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = observation_value2))
```

[image]